# Custom React component library does not work in not node running enviroment using global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react component library that I try to make work with applications not running in a node environment, the compiled version is included via a script tag.

Since it does not support imports, I am trying to assign it to the window.

When importing compiled js to the consumer project the following error:

`global is not defined` pops up and the window does not contain the `Components` object that I've assigned to the window.

Is there at all possible to make it work for both node and web environments?

Components: (index.ts)

```
import { Button } from "./src/components/Button/Button";
export { default as Button } from './src/components/Button/Button';

window.Components = {
    Button,
};
```

Webpack:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const { resolve } = require("path");

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const DtsBundleWebpack = require('dts-bundle-webpack')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.config')

module.exports = merge(commonConfig , {
    entry: resolve(__dirname, './', 'index.ts'),
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    node: {global: true},
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'Components'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                cache: true,
            }),
        ],
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'initial',
                },
                async: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'async',
                    chunks: 'async',
                    minChunks: 4,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new DtsBundleWebpack({
            name: "components",
            main: resolve(__dirname, './', 'index.d.ts'),
            out:  resolve(__dirname, './', 'dist/main.d.ts'),
        })
    ],
});
```

Comment: what is the problem with exporting and importing the Button component?

Comment: as you see in your webpack configuration file, you can use common node syntax to import modules and libraries. are you tried this?

Comment: @novonimo As mentioned, the consumer project is not running in node enviroment, and are included via `<script>` tag. The intention is to make it work for both node and web enviroments. Usually it is done by assigning comonents to a global window variable.

Comment: are you tried to implement it as node syntax? 
node js syntax will also work in browser and other environments.